# CSS: I tried to change the looking of images in HTML but it didn't work

Tags: html, css

I added a couple of  tags in HTML(already linked to CSS):

`<img src="../html/img/image1.jpg">`

`<img src="../html/img/image2.jpg">`

and had my CSS coded like:

```
img[src^="../html/img/"]{
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

However, it didn't apply to both tags in HTML no matter how many times I refreshed the web page.

Would you please tell me why my css attribute selector doesn't work? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried emptying the cache? Reload the page with `Ctrl+F5` so that your browser doesn't use an outdated version of your CSS.

Comment: Thank you I already tried but still same result ......

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply it to both img tags you could just do

```
img {
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

Comment: That will also apply to all other images that don't match the required pattern.

Answer (score 0):

How about this selector?

```
img[src*="/html/img/"]{
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but same result TT
Does it have something to do with  the brower  or the editor I use? I use Edge and Sublime Text respectively btw.

Comment: What is your edge version?

Comment: It's 96.0.1054.34

Comment: Close the window, and reopen the html or something again in new window.

Comment: still doesn't work smh. Thanks bro for taking your time answering me maybe it's temporary or some other technical issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... you just select the img not src or other code....

```
img{
border: 10px solid black
};
```

Comment: He wants to select images in html/img/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is based on the fact that your code doesn't work, but it does:

```css
img[src^="../html/img/"]{
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img src="../html/img/image1.jpg">

<img src="../html/img/image2.jpg">

<img src="not-bordered.jpg">
```

I suggest your look somewhere else for the problem.

Comment: yeah...that's why i am super bothered by this problem cuz I can't find out what's really going on. Thank you bro for the testing, I will eventually get this thing straight. Have a good day!

Comment: Try disabling the cache, f12 -> network -> disable cache